# construct a Wikidata SPARQL query to get a person's data by their Wikipedia URL

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata

how to construct a Wikidata SPARQL query to get a person's(single) data by their Wikipedia URL
I'm new to SPARQL and Wikidata, I tried this, but it takes a long time and returns no results:

```js
    SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?image ?article WHERE {
      ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
      ?article schema:about ?item .
      ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
      ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
      filter (?article = "<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldo_(footballer,_born_1977)>").
      
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  
    } LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you are getting a timeout because your query basically fetched all Wikidata person items with their Wikipedia article. Reason: You wrote `"<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldo_(footballer,_born_1977)>"` which is a string literal but not a URI. Remove the double quotes around it. Even better, simply put the URI in the place of the `?article` varibaler or at least use inline data via `VALUES` (or `BIND`) - a filter can be inefficient if the query optimizer doesn't inline it. Also no need for Wikipieda English chapter restriction, the Wikipedia URI does already denote English via `en.wikipedia`

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?image ?article WHERE {
  VALUES ?article {<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldo_(footballer,_born_1977)>}
      ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
      ?article schema:about ?item .

      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  
    } LIMIT 1`